# How to connect to a new server with similar old connection string info

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, winforms, entity-framework

Here in the company I'm working, we have migrated the current DB table structure and the Stored Procedures to a new DB; working so far.

The problem we are facing is that there isn't any way to get our app connected to the new DB. The reason? Probably some problem with the connection strings saved in the App.config (xml) file.

It's strange, because even if we have provided a similar Data Source, User ID, Password and Server structure as we had with the old DB, it simply refuses to connect and do any with it's functions.

The Database is running on SQL Server 2017 (same as before), and our app is developed in Winforms C#, using Entity Framework 6, and the EXECSQLSERVERPROCEDURE NuGet plugin.

This plugin in particular uses a special connection string (detailed below with the others) that doesn't use a "connectionString", but a "value" instead, and it's one of the parts that's failing, as well as the TableAdapter-based, filled DataGridViews. Only the EF6 connections and functions are working correctly.

I tried, from changing the Server Instance name, according to:
https://sqldbpool.com/2008/09/03/how-to-change-sql-server-instance-name/

So I didn't have to deal with special chars in the App.config; using HTML codes and entities for the Named Server Instance in Data Source (even in password with a asterisk, which we changed later without any effect), using this as reference:
https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/

And, changed the reference of the special Connection String for a regular one, calling by "name" instead of "key", because this one doesn't exist in regular Connection String definition (yeah, tried to add it, but didn't work).

Just to get a big amount of nothing and frustration (being on this one since Friday, just to put you all in context).

Connection Strings (in App.config):

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MYAPP.Properties.Settings.MYAPP" connectionString="Data Source=MYAPPSERVER;Initial Catalog=MYAPP;User ID=sa;Password=MYAPP2019;Server=192.168.*.*"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="MYAPPBD" connectionString="metadata=res://*/MYAPP.csdl|res://*/MYAPP.ssdl|res://*/MYAPP.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=192.168.*.*\MYAPP;initial catalog=MYAPP;user id=sa;password=MYAPP2019;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;"
      providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<appSettings>
    <add key="DBSQL" value="workstation id=server;packet size=4096;data source=MYAPPSERVER;initial catalog=MYAPP;user id=sa;password=MYAPP2019;server=192.168.*.*" />
    <add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value="" />
</appSettings>
```

The Definition of the Function that uses this "DBSQL" special Connection String (for getting a User's Privileges):

```
Dictionary<string, object> param = new Dictionary<string, object>();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
param.Add(new SqlParameter("@profile", profile));

dt = SQLSERVERPROCEDURE.SQLSERVER.Exec("DBSQL", "spRec_Privileges", param, dt);
```

You can see this plugin source code here, for reference:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/EXECSQLSERVERPROCEDURE/

Expecting to connect to DB with all functions and not only EF6 ones, because we can't parse DataTable / DataSet returning functions to do the same as they do with EF List's. As for the auto-filled with TableAdapters' DataGridViews, we can make SP's for loading and saving changes, but that would consume time we can't spare for it.

This is the error, even if User ID and Password are well-typed:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
   HResult = 0x80131904
   Message = Network-related or instance-specific error while establishing a connection to the SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to support remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection with SQL Server)
   Source = .Net SqlClient Data Provider
   Battery Tracking:
    in SQLSERVERPROCEDURE.SQLSERVER.Exec (String ConnectionName, String Procedure, Dictionary`2 Variable and Values, DataTable dt)
    in MYAPP.Class.User.GET_Usu_Privileges (Int32 profile) in C: \ Users \ User \ source \ repos \ MYAPP - EF Integration  \ MYAPP \ Class \ Users.cs: line 107

Internal Exception 1:
Win32Exception: Username or password are not correct
```

**Edit:** Queries among the DB works well. Even if using full Server-Name\Instance format, which is the original one, doesn't work. We aren't using Windows auth (this is only being used in Server); just SQL Server auth.

Comment: Use SQL Server Management Studio and see if you can query the database using SSMS.  Also check login window to get server/instance and check the credentials to see if Windows is being used.  If windows credential is used Do not use User ID and Password instead the connection string should have Integrated Security = true.  The catalog should be the Database name in the connection string.   It looks like you connection string has the instance and the database name the same which is wrong.  the instance is usually the version of the server like SQLExpress or SQLServer14.

Comment: I just added the answers to your points in the post as 1st edit. About the Data Source and the Initial Catalog, this part have been edited, but in production we have proper names that aren't the same, that points to what it needs to work.

Comment: The correctness of that connstring wholly relies on your network/db server setup, which we cannot verify for you (rendering this question unanswerable IMO). There is a Server Explorer in Visual Studio that allows you to connect to a database and generate a connection string from that entry. Use this to confirm that the connection details are actually correct. If VS can connect to your application, your .Net application should as well.

Comment: If you are changing or adding credentials than an database admin needs to set up the credentials.  Is your database local or remote?  Windows Authorization means the User Windows credentials are used.  Normally when a new database is installed it is setup to use Windows credentials of the user who did the installation.  Usually I recommend setting up a Windows Group Account and add users to the group so you do not need to modify the database credentials every time a new user is added.

Comment: Question: Did you enable SQL Server Authentication on the new DB server? Assuming this is a new instance/etc...

Comment: @Flater Don't worry about it, the Conn String it's fine. That's just a mirror of it, on how exactly it looks, for security reasons. I just tried the VS Conn String creator, and I think I have it, but need to test more things before saying "it works 100%"

Comment: @jdweng I have the control of the DB just as my partner does, so that's not a problem for my testing purposes. Back in time, we considered this, but I guess that the lack of expertise in this topic made us to keep SQL Server logins (not so many users need credentials), but eventually we may do that.

Comment: @CriticalError Yeah, it is enabled, just as TCP/IP logins through the company's intranet for remote logins. We can access Database Engine among our department, including the Server itself (with Windows Login).

Comment: @WolneySandoval: I wasn't saying I need to see your real connectionstring, I'm saying that we can't test the connection to your db server for you (even if we had the actual connectionstring).

Comment: Are you connecting to a local or remote machine?  If you are on a remote machine the local machine and remote machine has to be in the same windows group so windows secure connection will work.  This has nothing to do with the database credentials.  So first make sure you can connect on a local database.  Then go to a remote database.  You can check the database credentials by using SSMS explorer.  Open Databases :  Your Database : Security.  The User should be shown.  Compare to a working database.